# Is Ubuntu 32bit limited to 4Gigs of RAM

Tags: 12.04, pae

OK I have a Poweredge 2650 we are repurposing.  Since it doesn't support 64bit :( I have to use the 32bit.  However I know windoze has the 4gig limitation.  Does 12.04 i386?

Comment: Welcome to AU, can you please choose a more descriptive title relating to the content of your question, so others can find it more easily? Thanks and have a nice stay!

Answer (score 1):

Linux (as well as Windows [in some configurations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_address_extension#Microsoft_Windows)) supports [physical address extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_address_extension#Linux) to work around the 4 GiB limitation of 32 bit operating systems, and the i386 variant of Ubuntu ≥12.04 is PAE enabled.

From what I can see, the Poweredge 2650 has PAE support, but to be sure run `grep -m 1 -e '^flags\s*:' /proc/cpuinfo` and look for "pae" in the list of processor capabilities.